# prevent systemd / journald from logging socket-calls

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I just set up a new server (OpenSuse Leap 15.0) and installed the Check_MK-Agent. Every time my Check_MK-Servers polls this agent, this socket-access ist logged:

Apr 14 20:05:26 static systemd[1]: Started Check_MK (xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx).

As this happens every minute, my log-file is spammed with worthless information.

I already have two linux-machines monitored by my Check_MK-Server and none of them has these log-entrys. All three machines have syslogd running and I already invested hours in comparing the installations and conf-files without luck.

Does anybody know how to prevent syslogd from logging socket-calls?!

Comment: "_Every time my `Check_MK-Servers` polls this agent, this socket-access ist logged_". It's not `Check_MK-Servers` that's writing the message; it's `systemd`. That's where you need to look next.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to say - the syslogd on the machine with the check_mk-agent is my problem. 
By the way: I dindn't try but I fear that every process using the syslogd-socket-mechanism would cause syslogd to genereate these entrys in my log-file...
Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: It's not `syslogd` but `systemd` you need to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

*(copied from [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/1425388/prevent-systemd-journald-from-logging-socket-calls), where this was closed for some or other reason)*

---

systemd and syslogd do not log socket calls.

The Check_MK-agent is an "inetd service" – this means it [does not run persistently](https://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/checkmk-en/2009-December/000211.html) and does not create its own listener socket; instead it relies on a ["superserver"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) to do this job. Every new connection is accepted by the superserver, which then starts a new copy of Check_MK to handle that particular connection.

Traditionally the `inetd` or `xinetd` superserver programs are used for this purpose. Your newly installed system however uses the "socket activation" feature of systemd to achieve the same thing – in this system, the listener socket is represented by a `.socket` unit and each new instance is represented by a new au­to­mat­i­cal­ly generated `.service` unit.

So the log message is not about socket access at all – it literally says that *a service has been started.* There is no option to disable service startup logging.

To get rid of this message, deactivate the systemd .socket unit and reconfigure your Check_MK-agent to be started via xinetd (or traditional inetd, or any other alternative).